# Hiren's BootCD to update BIOS

Tags: updates, keyboard, dell, bios

I'm asking this here because I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on my computer and the only update available is a .exe file.

I have a brand-new Dell Inspiron 5593. I installed Ubuntu 20.04. Now the keyboard starting spazzing: keys repeating like there's no tomorrow. It's terrible. According to [Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=xxg7n), there's a BIOS update released a month ago that might affect the keyboard. I'm hoping that will help.

The problem is, Dell only released a .exe file. So now my choice is to [run FreeDOS](https://askubuntu.com/a/950211/1103141), which, quite frankly, terrifies me. I don't know computer architecture, firmware, or even Linux well enough to be completely comfortable running this whole process confident that I'm not going to brick my machine, and this answer is three years old, meaning it might be completely out-of-date.

Someone suggested another option to me: Running [Hiren's boot CD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) and simply running the .exe BIOS update file in there. Is this a legitimate, safe way to update the BIOS?

(Is the issue the BIOS altogether?)

I know this question is all over the place. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dell's BIOS can be updated from the current BIOS...

**BIOS**

**Updating the BIOS from BIOS Boot Menu (independent of operating system)**

Note 1: Before updating the BIOS, ensure that you suspend BitLocker encryption on a BitLocker-enabled system. If it is not enabled on your system, you can ignore this step. For information about how to disable BitLocker, see How to Enable or Disable BitLocker with TPM in Windows at support.dell.com.

Note 2: Do not turn off the power or interrupt the BIOS update process during the update.

Installation

1. Copy the downloaded file to a USB drive. The USB drive does not need to be bootable device.
2. Insert the USB drive into any USB port.
3. Power on the system.
4. At the DELL logo screen, press F12 to access the one-time boot menu.
5. Select BIOS Flash Update in the Other Options section.
6. Click the ... button to browse the USB drive to locate the downloaded file.
7. Select the file and click Ok.
8. Verify the existing system BIOS information and the BIOS update information.
9. Click Begin Flash Update.
10. Review the Warning message and click Yes to proceed with the update.
    The system restarts and displays a progress bar at the Dell logo screen. The system restarts again when the update is complete.